# Custom design of android push notification

Tags: android, cordova, google-cloud-messaging

How can I specify some custom logo and styling information to text. Or some custom action buttons just like music player notification in Android.

PS : I have successfully configured GCM with my app and is able to receive notification from GCM servers. And app is developed using **cordova**

Comment: where is you code implented? is it in the index.html or in another file? When you say *" I have successfully configured GCM with my app"* - does this mean you tested GCM in your browser? or you tested in a separate App?

Comment: It's in index.html and I have tested it on a physical device by building it in to an apk.

Comment: Okay. Can you add the entries for your `whitelist` and `CSP` to your question? And the the `whitelist` plugin entry in your `config.xml`?

Comment: When I said it's working it means I got push notification on my phone for my app but it's very basic one. I want to decorate if by applying some fonts, custom logo just like notification of hike messenger.or notification of any music player while it's playing.

Comment: That is nice. Please add the information I am asking for to your original post. Make sure to respond in the comments, or I wont see your changes.

Answer (score 1):

You should read more about rich notifications in Android. From official documentation:

> To have a notification appear in an expanded view, first create a NotificationCompat.Builder object with the normal view options you want. Next, call Builder.setStyle() with an expanded layout object as its argument.

Please see example below:

```
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle textDiv = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        textDiv.bigText(bodyMessage); 
        notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setTicker(bodyMessage)
        .setContentTitle(titleMessage)
        .setSmallIcon(notificationIcon)
        .setStyle(textDiv)
        .setPriority(1)//priority high
        .setVibrate(new long[0])
        .build();
```

More info you could see in official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) and [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am looking for a solution in Cordova or Ionic.